# local storage for add to cart option in angular 6

Tags: angular

I need to use session for add to cart option in e-commerce web application.
Session is not getting updated .
Till now I have implemented this:

```ts
onClickCart() {
     this
      .cartService
      .getCartDetails()
      .subscribe((data) => {
       localStorage.setItem('cartProducts', JSON.stringify(this.productInfoCart));
       console.log("Session data: ",localStorage.getItem('cartProducts'));
    });
  }
```

Comment: what do you mean by session is not getting updated? do you mean console.log is undefined?

Comment: When I add product to cart, in console.log value is getting incremented. But when i select another product from home page and add it to cart then new console.log opens and previous value in console.log is not getting incremented.

Comment: Can you provide complete code?

Comment: `this.productInfoCart` is not being updated when response comes in.

Comment: show us the data inside productInfoCart we will help you!!

Answer (score 0):

May be problem is you have not updated productInfoCart with the latest data

```
this.productInfoCart = []; // initialize

onClickCart(){
     this
      .cartService
      .getCartDetails()
      .subscribe((data) => {
       //this.productInfoCart = data; //add this line
       // if you want to add new item to cart
       this.productInfoCart.push(data);
       localStorage.setItem('cartProducts', JSON.stringify(this.productInfoCart));
       console.log("Session data: ",localStorage.getItem('cartProducts'));
    });
  }
```

If I understood your problem correctly then this should work for you
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-srslhc?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: This is giving me error:  Cannot read property 'push' of undefined.

Comment: I  am not able to post my complete code as its not accepting my code. Can you please suggest me how to post the code?

Comment: error meaning productInfoCart is not defined. Please check updated answer. Did you check the stackblitz link?

Comment: Yes I am going through stackblitz .

Comment: I have defined productInfoCart in this way: productInfoCart[]:any;

Comment: @AmrutaDeshpande do this productInfoCart[]:any = []; to resolve undefined error. Rest of the information you will get from stackblitz

Comment: Still its not working. Giving this error: ERROR TypeError: _this.productInfoCart.push is not a function

Comment: Giving this error: ERROR TypeError: _this.productInfoCart.push is not a function

Comment: @AmrutaDeshpande please post your complete code and also take a look at my stackblitz example. https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask go thorugh this link to know more on how to post code